# Не воспроизводиться видео в safari при клике на button

Tags: javascript, html

не могли бы помочь решить проблему с воспроизведением видео при клике на button. Дело в том что после клика почти во всех браузерах видео воспроизводиться кроме safari

```
<video class="anima-on" preload="auto" muted playisinline>
        <source src="images/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="images/1.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>


$('.preloader__btn').click(function (event) {
            $('.preloader').fadeOut('500');
            setTimeout(() => {
                $('.anima video')[0].play()
            }, 100)
})
```

Comment: Safari на MacOS или IOS?

Comment: в macos и в ios